# Check array key and replace if exist Php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have following array ($result)

```
Array
(
    [check_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => male
            [1] => female
        )

    [email] => abc@xyz.com
)
```

I just want to check

1. Whether array key contain word "check"(id will dynamic, id can be 1 or 2 ...)
2. If "check" key exist then all values (checkbox) should be like "male,female"
3. I want to replace "check_1" with "user_1"

I want output like folllowing way

```
Array
(
    [user_1] => Array
        (
           [0] male,female
        )
  
)
```

How can i do this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you see this A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3932051/2960971

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use loops with functions like `str_contains` and `str_replace` and `implode` for concatenation.

```php
$data = [
            'check_1'=>["male"],
            'email'=>["abc@xyz.com"],
            'check_3'=>["male", "female"],
        ];
$res = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if(strrpos($key, "check")!==false){
        $res[str_replace("check", "user", $key)] = implode(', ', $value);
    }
}
echo "<PRE>";
print_r($res);
/*
Array
(
    [user_1] => male
    [user_3] => male, female
)
*/
```

Comment: 1: Giving me following error
Call to undefined function str_contains()

Comment: what version of PHP do you use?

Comment: Not everyone has embraced php8 :) Many are acclimating to the change to 7 still haha.

Comment: @ Steverest1 : i am using Php 7

Answer (score 0):

You would use :

```php
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    if(substr($key,0,6) == 'check_') {
        $id = substr($key, strrpos($key,'_'));
        $result['user' . $id][] = implode(',',$value);
        unset($result[$key]);
    }
}
```

It will return :

```
Array
(
    [email] => abc@xyz.com
    [user_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => male,female
        )

)
```

Comment: i want male and female in one key/column , i want out put like [0] => male,female

Comment: not working,And options ( male , female ) is not staic , it can be dynamic